# Java- OO accessing variables

Tags: java, variables

I am looking for easy but efficient "OO" way to access a variable from one class in another in Java. I'll add an example of what I'm looking for:

```
public class GuiClass {
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    public void frameSeting() {
        frame.setSize(200, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GuiClass guiCla = new GuiClass();
        guiCla.frameSeting();
    }
}
```

For example I'd want to set title of frame in another class:

```
public class GuiTitle {
    // The way to set title using 
    // frame.setTitle() method
}
```

I think that I could use accessors and mutators but what would be the way to do something like that without creating two instances of same class?

Comment: What makes you think you would need two instances?

Comment: Why do you think that accesors and mutators require two instances of a class?

Comment: @Gendarme How would I make it w/o 2 instances?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pass in `frame` to `GuiTitle`? Like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GuiTitle myTitle = new GuiTitle();
    myTitle.setTitleOnFrame(frame);

 }
```

Then in your `GuiTitle` class:

```
class GuiTitle {
  String myTitle = "blah blah myTitle";
  void setTitleOnFrame(Frame myFrame) {
      myFrame.setTitle(myTitle);
  }
}
```